# Is there a way of hiding data from users in a package in R?

Tags: r

I've built a package of tools in R for doing things on a project and I want to share the package with my colleagues in a user friendly way.

There are a number of data files built into the package - including many which work with the functions I've developed. When I use my own package I don't mind loading the data file and then using that with my functions. However for other users I don't want them to have the hassle of doing that, I just want them to use the function and for the dataset to be used in the background.

I should say the data isn't secret, I don't need to keep it from the users, I just don't want it to distract them when they type my package name and have to select from a long list of functions in a sea of data files.

So I would do something like:

```
user_data <- c("Strawberry","Pistachio","Chocolate Chip")
my_df <- fat_pats_tools::ice_cream_flavours
results <- fat_pats_tools::ice_cream_detector_function(user_data, my_df)
```

But I would like my users to be able to do:

```
user_data <- c("Strawberry","Pistachio","Chocolate Chip")
results <- fat_pats_tools::ice_cream_detector_function(user_data) # using the internal ice_cream_flavours data
```

And I would also like them to only see the list of functions when they type 'fat_pats_tools::' in RStudio, not get lost in a load of data file names.

So two questions I'd be grateful for some advice on:

1. How do I add data to a package which is accessible to my functions but not my users? (I currently use usethis:: and devtools:: to create the 'public' data)
2. How do I reference the private data created within my functions so R knows to search within the current package (e.g. 'fat_pats_tools')

I've struggled to find an answer to this online as most assumes the data is secret and needs encryption etc or needs to be in a repository such as Github etc. Mine is just to make my package easier/slicker to use for people new to R/RStudio particularly as there could be around ten data packages used by functions.

Thanks in advice for your help and apologies if I missed something obvious!

Comment: Read https://r-pkgs.org/data.html. I think you want to put your data into `R/sysdats.rda` (to keep it relatively private) or `data/ice_cream_flavours.rda` and then define your functions such that the default value for `my_df` use this unless overridden.

Comment: I normally do this by having an environment that is part of the package. For example, your environment could be called `pat_data`, then you would have all your data objects stored within it. Any functions that need the data would refer to them by `pat_data$ice_cream_flavour` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a walk-through for how to formally add data to a package and make it the default data for a function.

(All of this is documented in https://r-pkgs.org/data.html and other places.)

## Public Data, Same Package

```r
devtools::create("mypkg")
# ✔ Creating 'C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/20770390/75193911/mypkg/'
# ✔ Setting active project to 'C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/20770390/75193911/mypkg'
# ✔ Creating 'R/'
# ✔ Writing 'DESCRIPTION'
# Package: mypkg
# Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
# Version: 0.0.0.9000
# Authors@R (parsed):
#     * First Last <first.last@example.com> [aut, cre] (YOUR-ORCID-ID)
# Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
# License: `use_mit_license()`, `use_gpl3_license()` or friends to
#     pick a license
# Encoding: UTF-8
# Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
# RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
# ✔ Writing 'NAMESPACE'
# ✔ Setting active project to '<no active project>'
setwd("mypkg")
```

Optionally set up `data-raw`, which helps you to formalize a process for creating the data.

```r
usethis::use_data_raw("mydata", FALSE)
# ✔ Setting active project to 'C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/20770390/75193911/mypkg'
# ✔ Creating 'data-raw/'
# ✔ Adding '^data-raw$' to '.Rbuildignore'
# ✔ Writing 'data-raw/mydata.R'
# • Finish the data preparation script in 'data-raw/mydata.R'
# • Use `usethis::use_data()` to add prepared data to package
```

Now edit the `data-raw/mydata.R` file to read:

```r
mydata <- mtcars[1:4, 1:3]
usethis::use_data(mydata, overwrite = TRUE)
```

and source the file. If you don't want to use `data-raw/..`, you can simply call the `use_data(..)` command there manually (with one or more datasets that you've defined elsewhere).

From here, let's write a function in `R/fun.R`:

```r
#' Pass-through to head
#'
#' @param n integer
#' @param data data, defaults to mypkg::mydata
#' @return data.frame
#' @export
myfun <- function(n = 3, data = mypkg::mydata) utils::head(data, n = n)
```

Now we can document (which loads) and use it.

```r
devtools::document()
# ℹ Updating mypkg documentation
# ℹ Loading mypkg
# Writing NAMESPACE
# Writing myfun.Rd

myfun(1)
#           mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4  21   6  160
myfun(1, data=mtcars[4:6,1:5])
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08
```

Though not required, you can [document your dataset](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-documenting-data) by adding a file such as `R/mydata.R`:

```r
#' My data, a subset of mtcars
#'
#' A subset of data from the infamous mtcars dataset
#'
#' @format ## `who`
#' A data frame with 4 rows and 3 columns:
#' \describe{
#'   \item{mpg}{Miles per gallon}
#'   \item{cyl}{Number of cylinders}
#'   \item{disp}{Displacement}
#'   ...
#' }
"mydata"
```

then `devtools::document()` again, and now your users can (if they choose) read `?mypkg::mydata`.

---

## "Private" Data, Same Package

If having the users see the data.frame names when they type in `mypkg::<tab>` really is something to be avoided, then instead of making the data *public*, you can make it *private* using

```r
usethis::use_data_raw("privdata", FALSE)
```

and in the `data-raw/privdata.R` file,

```r
privdata <- iris[1:3,]
usethis::use_data(privdata, overwrite = TRUE, internal = TRUE)
```

When this is sourced, we find `R/sysdata.rda` and nothing new in `data/..`.

Once we document, we can see that it is not readily visible but can still be accessed,

```r
mypkg::privdata
# Error: 'privdata' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mypkg'
mypkg:::privdata
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

which means we would modify our function to be:

```r
myfun
# function(n = 3, data = privdata) utils::head(data, n = n)
# <environment: namespace:mypkg>
myfun()
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

No need for `mypkg:::` in the function declaration. The caveat with this is that other *packages* will either (a) not have access to `privdata`, ergo the "private" part; or (b) will need to use `mypkg:::privdata` to access it. The use of `:::` is generally discouraged; from https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports:

> Using `foo:::f` instead of `foo::f` allows access to unexported objects. This is generally not recommended, as the existence or semantics of unexported objects may be changed by the package author in routine maintenance.

Meaning: an author can have any type of unexported objects in their package, and has liberty to change/delete them without notification. The premise is that the author *exports* functions they intend users to use, and *does not export* things that are either fragile, not-yet-ready, likely-to-change, or any number of reasons.

Having said that, for interactive use, it's perfectly fine to do temporarily avail yourself of that private data via `mypkg:::privdata`, nobody will judge you :-)

---

## Public Data, Different Package

*(I should note up front that this helps to mitigate your concerns for users seeing frame names when they type `mypkg::<tab>`, since the data is not under `mypkg::` but under `mypkgdata::<tab>` instead.)*

If your data is large, if the change frequency for functions versus data are significantly different, if the dev/release cycle is executed by different people or through different policy channels, etc ... it might be advantageous to have separate packages for *functions* and *data*. This pattern is used in (for example) `naturalearth` with its `naturalearthdata` package (see https://blog.r-hub.io/2020/05/29/distribute-data/).

```r
devtools::create("mypkgdata")
setwd("mypkgdata")
usethis::use_data_raw("mydata")
### edit `data-raw/mydata.R` as above and source it
### optionally document the data in `R/mydata.R` as above
devtools::document()
devtools::install() ## optionally `::build()` it for others
```

Now go back to the `mypkg` package to:

- update the function to use the new data, notice the `@import` roxygen2 tag

  ```r
  #' Pass-through to head
  #'
  #' @param n integer
  #' @param data data, defaults to mypkg::mydata
  #' @return data.frame
  #' @export
  #' @import mypkgdata
  myfun <- function(n = 3, data = mypkgdata::mydata) utils::head(data, n = n)
  ```
- remove the data files from `mypkg`: `data-raw/mydata.R`, `data/mydata.rda`, and `R/mydata.R` (if you documented it); you can either manually remove `man/mydata.Rd` or rerun `devtools::document()`
- update the `DESCRIPTION` file:

  ```r
  usethis::use_package("mypkgdata")
  # ✔ Adding 'mypkgdata' to Imports field in DESCRIPTION
  # • Refer to functions with `mypkgdata::fun()`
  ```

  (Notice that this step both adds `mypkgdata` to the `DESCRIPTION` file `Imports:` section as well as adding `import(mypkgdata)` to `NAMESPACE`, both are essential.)

With all that, it works as before.

```r
myfun
# function(n = 3, data = mypkgdata::mydata) utils::head(data, n = n)
# <environment: namespace:mypkg>
myfun(3)
#                mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108
```

Comment: This is a really useful and comprehensive answer, many thanks. I followed the guidance under the "Private Data, Same Package" and done a test of this and it works superbly. Thanks very much indeed for this.

Comment: Just a quick follow up query please. In this excellent answer you mention @r2evans that it is frowned upon to use the format fat_pats_tools:::privdata and just to cite privdata in the function. Unfortunately when I do this it cannot find the object privdata. However when I use fat_pats_tools:::privdata it works perfectly. I am perfectly happy with how it works but I'm minded that you said this is discouraged. Could I run into problems later if I do this and is there something I've missed which is preventing the function finding the data unless I cite the package name? Many thanks.

Comment: @FatPat, I've edited my answer to add more discussion around the use of `:::`, hope it helps.